# What does “fechados com Bolsonaro” mean?

Tags: significado

I see this used by supporters of President Bolsonaro, e.g. on Twitter as #fechadoscombolsonaro.

I know fechado means closed - is this some kind of pun on the idea of places being closed due to Covid-19 lockdowns?

Does fechados have a sense meaning “to be close [to someone’s way of thinking]”. The way I see it used is almost like “I stand with Bolsonaro”. I have not found any dictionary listing this sense but that’s my impression of how it is being used.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**"Estou fechado com Bolsonaro e não abro."**

**You're right, it's not to be taken literally.** "Estou fechado" is a slang phrase for "I totally agree with", "I'm committed to", or "I'm wholeheartedly dedicated to".

It's often followed by "e não abro", also a slang phrase meaning "and I won't change my mind", "I won't rethink", "won't reassess".

"ok, estamos fechados" = "ok, agreed."

Comment: Eu percebo, companheiro, a frustração imensa por que muitos brasileiros devem estar a passar :( ... força aí, lembra-te que «não há bem que sempre dure [mas também] *nem mal que nunca acabe*».

Comment: Considerando o extremismo, talvez seja fechado como um pacto. "Closed a pact".

Comment: So it’s like “[I’ve] closed [a deal with somebody]” in English?

Comment: @jl6 No, it's stronger than closing a deal, besides, to close a deal, there has to be an agreement between both parties, while you can support someone without them even knowing about it.

Comment: “My mind is closed on this matter” but without the negative connotation of being closed-minded that English has?

Comment: @jl6 I think that's subjective. It can be seen as close-minded to the ones who disagree, depending on the subject.

Comment: fechar um contrato: to make a deal, to close on a deal, to be in agreement with, in slang. to agree with.

Answer (score 0):

"Estou fechado com Bolsonaro."

Não deve ser interpretado, pois aqui no Brasil usamos a palavra “Fechado”, como gíria.

Por exemplo : vamos fechar esse negócio ?
Fecharemos parceria, oque acha?

A origem da gíria em si é desconhecida, porém utilizada no país todo para entrar em um contrato ou grupo. Acredito que essa gíria tenha surgido nas favelas, em grupos criminosos. Porém e só uma teoria. Normalmente se usa a gíria, quando está finalizando um negócio, e pessoas informais utilizam essa gíria.

Comment: Bem-vindo, Joao Victor. Obrigado pela contribuição. Note que sua postagem pode ser melhorada em dois aspectos: 1) responder a pergunta - agora ela apenas afirma, incorretamente, que "gírias não devem ser interpretadas"; 2) citar fontes que fundamentem suas suposições - como está, parecem não ter base alguma.

Answer (score 0):

significa estar do mesmo lado de...torcer por... ou fazer parte do mesmo time.